# How to build WordPress theme which allows to manage multiple similar sites?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to make WP theme which allows me to manage multiple similar sites. I want to select a site from a dropdown list and configure by adding widgets. Apart from that it would be great if it's possible to set domain name for each of that site.

Is it possible with WordPress admin to manage multiple sites?

Comment: This is a native WordPress feature. It's called Multisite. Read up on it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Wow, thanks for the reference!